# How can I install Application Request Routing ARR 3.0 in Windows 10 Preview?

Tags: iis, arr, windows-10, arr-3.0

When I try to Install Application Request Routing I get an error "IIS Version 7.0 or greater is required to install Microsoft Application Request Rounting 3.0". Windows 10 has IIS 10.0, so it should be possible, but I guess that Microsoft hasn't fixed the version check yet. Are there any workarounds available for this?

Windows version: Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview. Build 10074.

[image: ARR3 install in Windows 10 Preview]

Comment: Have you tried installing it using MSI which can be found at http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/3/D/63D67918-483E-4507-939D-7F8C077F889E/requestRouter_x64.msi for 64bit or http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/3/D/63D67918-483E-4507-939D-7F8C077F889E/requestRouter_x86.msi for 32 bit

Comment: No it failed as well "IIS Version 7.0 or greater...". I also tried the stand alone install (http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/A/4/2A4DFCD2-E577-422C-8435-0D8F5D9085E8/ARRv3_setup_amd64_en-us.EXE) but it also failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit of hacky solution if it suits your requirement.
Open MSI file in tool called ORCA and remove Launch condition (highlighted in screenshot) as show in screenshot. Save modified MSI and use it for installing on Win10 preview machine.
[image: Edit ARR MSI in ORCA]

Comment: An important blog post was recently deleted by Microsoft, which was written on June 12, 2015, announcing ARR 3.0, URL Rewrite 2.0, and other upgraded OOB components for IIS 10 and above. There is no need to use this hack any more. I also wrote a personal blog with more info https://blog.lextudio.com/status-of-iis-out-of-band-modules-80a3af57c489