# How to run .net framework 4 build application on Windows 2016 Servers?

Tags: c#, iis, msbuild, wix, windows-installer

I have an old webservice installer built on .netframework 4 which is running on Windows 2008 and when i try to install the installer on Windows Server 2016, i am getting the below error.

**Error Message : "This setup requires Internet Information Server 5.1 or higher and Windows XP or higher. This setup cannot be installed on Windows 2000."**

Is it possible to run this old webservice installer to the new 2016 without rebuild my solution?

Comment: Please show us what the [LaunchCondition Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/launchcondition-table) looks like in this MSI - once you have gotten hold of a tool to view it.

Comment: [See similar question with Orca screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30083040/129130). And [the full size screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSHWJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

[***LaunchCondition Table***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/launchcondition-table): Most likely there is an entry in the LaunchCondition table of that MSI - if it is an MSI - which prevents installation. I say most likely because it could also be a **custom action** - please check the launch condition table first and get back to us. Launch conditions must evaluate to true for the setup to allow itself to be installed. You can "hotfix" this by using a tool capable of writing to MSI files: [How can I compare the content of two (or more) MSI files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546)

You are supposed to make a transform file **`*.mst`** (a database fragment) and apply it at installation time to change the original MSI installer. However, sometimes I make backups of the original installer and zap simple stuff like launch conditions *if they are wrong in the first place*. A transform becomes too cumbersome for ad-hoc stuff. But should be used if you intend to distribute through SCCM etc...

***Compatibility***: Even if you hotfix the MSI file and it installs you obviously won't see the webservice working if there are technical reasons why it won't work on that machine. Launch conditions are a sign that something must be present on the machine for the application to work. However, sometimes people are a bit trigger happy with their launch conditions and make packages that are a bit too restrictive.

***Note***: first check if IIS is installed on the box.